# Kafka Stream daily aggregation

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Given I have the following AVRO schema or object format

```
consumption {
   consumptionId;
   consumptionTime;
   region;
   amount;
}
```

I would like to aggregate by consumptionId and sum the totalAmount for each consumptionId for a given window. The given window is *[endOfDay-24h, endOfDay]* and the *endOfDay* is different for each region.

- for region: USA, NYC, the *endOfDay* is 18:00
- for region: UK, London,the *endOfDay* is 20:00

Currently I am playing with it, but I am not really happy with the outcome. Can anyone suggest a good approach?

Do I need to create a stream for each region(endOfDay)?
I'm at the beginning of my Kafka-streams journey and I would be really grateful if someone could help me :)

Comment: Not sure how Avro is relevant, as the data could be in any format, but I'd recommend using UTC time. Otherwise, you'll be fighting daylight savings time, for example, with this approach every 6 months or so.

Comment: Also, not sure about Kafka Streams... You could use S3/JDBC Sink Connectors, then partition by region, so have two paths in a S3 bucket or database fields like `region=NYC` and `region=London`, then you can use external tools like Spark or Athena to run some query like  `consumptionTime BETWEEN T and addHours(T, 24)`

Comment: would be great to have something like partitioning in kafka streams

Comment: I mean, it kinda does... You can [prefixScan](https://kafka.apache.org/31/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/state/ReadOnlyKeyValueStore.html#prefixScan(P,PS)) a store for `NYC/` or `London/`, but that will not allow a time-range query like a non key-value database would be able to support.

Comment: yes, that's the problem :( I need to add the TimeWindows processing for each region. 
I was thinking of leveraging .split().branch(predicate), loop through multiple regions and somehow pass in a consumer, but not sure it works

Comment: You could have several such prefix keys like `NYC/20220912-0000-0100`, `NYC/20220912-0100-0200`, etc, but then every day, you have 23 keys. Every year, for every region, you have over 8300 keys... I don't think that would scale well in a KTable.

Comment: I am thinking to use the split stream and process the substreams. Each substream could have a different windowing. But I have never seen this case implemented  before 
(https://developer.confluent.io/tutorials/split-a-stream-of-events-into-substreams/confluent.html)